# How to force repainting my scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, directx

I'm coding a script in Unity that is applying a sequence of motions to my camera, for it to follow a predefined path. I need to repaint the scene in between every small motion otherwise the scene is drawn only when it reaches its final position. 
I tried a lot of options but I just can't find something working for me.

I already tried :

```
SceneView.RepaintAll();
HandleUtility.Repaint();
```

and it can't find the Repaint() method from the Editor or EditorWindow classes.

Any idea ?

Comment: I do not unterstand. You're trying to move your camera : ok. Your doing this in the <X>Update() method right ?
I don't get it with all of you're repaint stuff.

Comment: In LateUpdate() I'm calling for my input handler that does predefined moves on the camera, based on the current input. In this, I have lets say a method that say, if you hit this particular key, the camera will find its path and go to a Top view in a Quadratic motion. Every methods used are already coded in my class, but when it processes, it wont be visually refreshed until it reaches the last frame. Therefore, I try to trigger a repaint in between every frame within the process (after each small motion).

Comment: Ok I might have unterstand. The thing is that your calculate all of your position stuff in your LateUpdate(). Get the input in the Update() method and apply your movement in the LateUpdate()

Comment: Check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) the Unity execution order of event function doc. It can you help unterstand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know if it is actually possible to issue the rendering process multiple times per frame. can't you just distribute your camera motion over several frames and let the engine work as it is supposed to?

Comment: I did it but I still have the same issue. I know a way to work around this but I would prefer to do it this way with a repaint, it would be nicer logically speaking. So it's not critical but I'd be interested in understanding how it works.

Comment: I'll probably spread it over several frames as suggested, that's what I planned to do anyway, but I was just interested in finding out whether it was possible or not. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rendering process start after each Update(). Let process your motion logic in several Update with interpolation between each update.